# What is the farthest that a "human satellite" has been from their spacecraft?

Tags: eva, record, astronaut-propulsion

There are several news items about the recent passing of astronaut Bruce McCandless II, and they generally refer to his work developing, and then using the [Manned Maneuvering Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manned_Maneuvering_Unit) (MMU).

- BBC: [Bruce McCandless, who made first untethered space flight, dies at 80](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-42465059)
- NBC: [NASA astronaut Bruce McCandless, first to fly untethered in space, dies at 80](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/nasa-astronaut-bruce-mccandless-first-fly-untethered-space-dies-80-n832236)
- NPR: [Bruce McCandless, First Astronaut To Fly Untethered In Space, Has Died](https://www.npr.org/2017/12/22/517135809/bruce-mccandless-first-astronaut-to-fly-untethered-in-space-has-died)

Access to the original New York Times article describing McCandless' first use of the MMU is provided in a free sample from their archive [TimesMachine](https://timesmachine.nytimes.com/timesmachine/1984/02/08/231504.html?pageNumber=1).

**Question:** What is the farthest distance that an astronaut has been *free-floating in space* from any spacecraft other than a space suit, presumably with an attached propulsion unit?

I'm not sure if a "how many times" question should be asked separately, or if it's better to include here. I'm guessing this hasn't happened very many times.

---

NASA video of McCandless: [Astronaut Bruce McCandless II Floats Free in Space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvnC--JjDBw), video and much more: [NASA Remembers Astronaut Bruce McCandless II](https://www.nasa.gov/astronautprofiles/mccandless).

**below:** "This Feb. 7, 1984 photo made available by NASA shows astronaut Bruce McCandless II participating in a spacewalk a few meters away from the cabin of the Earth-orbiting space shuttle Challenger, using a nitrogen-propelled Manned Maneuvering Unit." Photo: AP. From [here](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/nasa-astronaut-bruce-mccandless-first-fly-untethered-space-dies-80-n832236)

[image]

**below:** "On Feb. 12, 1984, Bruce McCandless ventured away unrestrained from the safety of his spaceship, which no previous astronaut had done. He could do it because of a brand-new, jet-powered backpack." Photo: NASA. *Cropped* from [here](https://www.npr.org/2017/12/22/517135809/bruce-mccandless-first-astronaut-to-fly-untethered-in-space-has-died).

[image]

Comment: I assume the moon walks aren't eligible, despite probably having the distance record?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto that's a good point! The "human satellite" term isn't clear enough. I'll edit the question.

Comment: This first MMU mission is probably it.  Not sure how to confirm though. They were only used on three missions in 1984 and never again :(

Comment: There was actually a 4th, but with a different unit, the SAFER.

Comment: Yeah, I meant MMU.  SAFERs were worn on many, many missions, and were far less capable.

Comment: Uhoh - You say: "Free floating in space", I don't want to twist your question but my answer would be 38,969 m (127,851 ft) (23.3884 miles) **IF** I am not violating the constraints of your question: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Bull_Stratos .

Comment: @Rob 39 km is not beyond the *Karman line* yet, and the jumper did not emerge from a *spacecraft*, but it's good to keep this in mind, thanks!

Comment: Comment collapse blinds me yet again hah.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

None of them were particularly far. The [first flight](http://spacefacts.de/mission/english/sts-41b.htm) shows a distance of 325 feet (99 m). The best record I can find for [STS-41-C](http://spacefacts.de/mission/english/sts-41c.htm) says the shuttle came within 200 feet (63 m) of the satellite, and the last was done via the MMU. and the best guess I have from STS-51-A is [35 feet](http://spacefacts.de/mission/english/sts-51a.htm). The tests of SAFER on STS-64 was just around the robotic arm, so I'm assuming less then that.

Best guess: 325 feet (99 m). Small chance of a further distance.

Comment: " Bruce McCandless then moved 45 m (150 ft) out from Challenger, returned to the payload bay, flew out to 96 m (315 ft) and returned, then moved out again to about 99 m (325 ft). " - from the first link.

Comment: Woops... Will correct, good catch!

Comment: It would be great if you could put the meter count into your answer (comments might be deleted more easily).

Comment: Confirmation; astronaut Michael Lopez-Alegria (current president of the [Association of Space Explorers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_of_Space_Explorers)) can be heard to round it to 100 meters in a BBC interview [here between `14:00` and `19:47`](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/w172vr1jhn7rhmt), along with some recordings of astronaut Bruce McCandless himself.