# How to estimate which astronaut ends up furthest from the ISS after one orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, crewed-spaceflight, eva

Three astronauts; [Goofus, Gallant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goofus_and_Gallant) and [Zippy the Pinhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zippy_the_Pinhead) play a game. All three take their cold gas thruster-powered jet packs and quickly move 100 meters away from the ISS. For some reason after accelerating and decelerating to a stop, *all three ran out of propellant.*

Goofus moved 100 meters out in front of the ISS while Gallant moved to the side; and Zippy the Pinhead moved 100 meters farther from Earth so that he could be seen from ISS' purported **zenith-facing window** ([1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9661/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30716/12102), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22050/12102)).

The four position vectors at the beginning for ISS, Goofy, Gallant and Zippy are:

```
x0 = [a, 0, 0.] + [a, 100, 0.] + [a, 0, 100.] + [a+100, 0, 0.]
```

and all four starting velocity vectors are `[0, speed, 0.]`

After one orbit around the Earth had elapsed, how far did each of our three heroes end up from the ISS?

---

This is what I got, but I'd prefer to accept an answer based more on math and principles than brute-force numerical integration.

J2 is important but for the purposes of other answers it can be ignored.

[image: Goofus, Gallant and Zippy the Pinhead start 100 meters from ISS]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint as ODEint

def deriv(X, t):
    x, v = X.reshape(2, -1)
    accs = []
    for xx in x.reshape(-1, 3):
        acc = -xx * GMe * ((xx**2).sum())**-1.5
        if use_J2:
            x, y, z = xx
            xsq, ysq, zsq = xx**2
            rm7 = (xsq + ysq + zsq)**-3.5
            accJ2x = x * rm7 * (6*zsq - 1.5*(xsq + ysq))
            accJ2y = y * rm7 * (6*zsq - 1.5*(xsq + ysq))
            accJ2z = z * rm7 * (3*zsq - 4.5*(xsq + ysq))
            acc -= J2 * np.hstack((accJ2x, accJ2y, accJ2z))
        accs.append(acc)
    return np.hstack((v, np.hstack((accs))))

halfpi, pi, twopi = [f*np.pi for f in (0.5, 1, 2)]
GMe = 3.98600435436E+14 # earth (from DE430)
Re = 6378136.3 # meters
J2_earth = -1.08262545E-03  # unitless
J2 = J2_earth * (GMe * Re**2) 

inc = 51*pi/180.

a = Re + 400*1000.
speed = np.sqrt(GMe/a) # close enough for government work
x0 = [a, 0, 0.] + [a, 100, 0.] + [a, 0, 100.] + [a+100, 0, 0.]
v0 = 4*[0, speed, 0.]
X0 = np.array(x0 + v0, dtype=float).reshape(-1, 3)
s, c = [f(inc) for f in (np.sin, np.cos)]
R = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, c, -s], [0, s, c]])
X0 = (X0[:, None, :] * R).sum(axis=2).flatten()

times = np.arange(0, 92*60, 10)

use_J2 = True
answer, info = ODEint(deriv, X0, times, full_output=True)
use_J2 = False
answer_noJ2, info = ODEint(deriv, X0, times, full_output=True)

s0, s1 = answer.shape
answers = answer.T[:s1>>1].reshape(-1, 3, s0)
if True:
    plt.figure()
    for a in answers[1:]:
        r = np.sqrt(((a-answers[0])**2).sum(axis=0))
        plt.plot(times/60., r)
    plt.title('Goofus, Gallant and Zippy the Pinhead start 100 meters from ISS')
    plt.ylim(0, None)
    plt.xlabel('minutes')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Don't forget to account for the quadrupole moment!

Comment: @OrganicMarble I had you in mind, it's there as J2!

Comment: This doesn't seem right. The guy 100m in front of ISS is still exactly in the same orbit, just with a slight phase shift. His distance shouldn't change. The guys above and sideways are in elliptical orbit and at a different inclination, repsectively, these curves seem about right.

Comment: @asdfex It's directly in front in the cartesian sense, not *along track*. I've added the initial vectors in the text. For ISS and Goofus it's [a, 0, 0]  and  [a, 100, 0] meters. However Goofus is still moving with ISS' velocity. At least that's what I've simulated.

Comment: @asdfex btw those are cartesian coordinates before I rotated to an inclination of 51 degrees (rotated everybody at once, pivoting about the x-axis (the ISS) at t=0).

Comment: @asdfex I'll have another look today, thanks for the feedback! I certainly won't require any answer to match my calculation, it's offered as background to the question and "my attempt to solve the problem".

Comment: The tiny difference between straight ahead and ahead in orbit shouldn't result in a large change like this.

Comment: Please add a key describing what the 3 colors represent, and don't forget the units on the y-axis.

Comment: @asdfex the reason I resist making plots look too good is that somebody may come along later and use it out of context as if it's absolutely correct. I make them deliberately less-than-user-friendly because they're not peer-reviewed. FYI I've taken [DavidHammen's advice](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23408/how-to-calculate-the-planets-and-moons-beyond-newtonss-gravitational-force#comment103549_23409) and used the simple yet [symplectic](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/29149/17869) method [semi-implicit Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method)...

Comment: @uhoh Leaving out information makes it for all of us much more complicated to understand what you did. Essentially we have to recreate all your work to get started. With labels and such one can start right ahead.

Comment: @asdfex But to "we can't understand it but we simultaneously think it's wrong" I can only say I disagree.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104321/discussion-on-question-by-uhoh-how-to-estimate-which-astronaut-ends-up-furthest).

Comment: I suppose the recent downvote was a reminder that I'd said that "[If nobody posts an answer, then I'll post one myself. This is not a hard question.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53504926#53504926)"