# Leaving the ISS orbit

Tags: iss, orbit

Working on a project of sorts and I can't wrap my head around this at all., have a question regarding leaving the ISS orbit.  If, let us say as an example, an astronaut jumped out of a capsule which was traveling towards the ISS, and that astronaut missed the ISS and kept going.  Would he:

1. Enter his own orbit at a different inclination? and would he come in contact with the ISS eventually again? Or chances of that would be slim?
2. Would he keep going into outer space?

I know it may sound odd, but any help with this would be appreciated.

EDIT!  I can't thank you all enough, all this information is amazing.  Hopefully, I'll update you soon with the reasoning for my query.

Comment: You should think about the difference between an astronaut outside the ISS and a satellite of similar size and weight. The orbital differences.

Comment: You might want to take a look at SuitSat (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuitSat)

Comment: Different but related: [How to estimate which astronaut ends up furthest from the ISS after one orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41350/12102) (currently unanswered, I should probably do that)  [What kinds of things have been tossed out of the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17739/12102) and [What radar-trackable steel ball was thrown from the ISS before October 2015?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48738/12102) and [Are the cubesats deployed from the ISS always directed “nadir and retrograde”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29531/12102)...

Comment: ...and [Parallel orbits around the Earth - effectively?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22018/12102)

Comment: You need to specify which direction the astronaut approaches the ISS from, as different things happen. From behind, it'll appear that the astronaut does larger and larger circles around the ISS. From the side, he'll go past it, slow down, stop, and return towards it, missing by a slightly larger amount, slow down, return, miss again..

Comment: From under, basically, the same side as they dock at.  But imagine the capsule going way too fast and being on a course to miss the ISS completely, overshooting it by a large margin and only way to get to the ISS is to jump out and hopefully not miss the ISS.  And the astronaut does just that, misses it, and ends up, I'm assuming, in his own orbit, pretty much the same if not slightly different than the ISS.  But because at the jump-off point he's traveling faster than the ISS I'm also assuming that by missing he would end up in a completely different orbit.

Answer (score 4):

The capsule and the ISS are both in orbit around the Earth; almost the same orbit, if the capsule and ISS are within sight of each other, and the relative speed between the two is modest. If the astronaut carefully lets go of the capsule without pushing away, he will remain in exactly the same orbit as the capsule.

Jumping away from the capsule imparts a small change in speed and thus a small alteration in orbit, so now all three elements (capsule, ISS, and astronaut) are in very similar orbits. Whether the astronaut returns to the vicinity of the spacecraft or the ISS later depends on which direction he jumps.

The astronaut will not keep going into outer space unless he can impart about 3500 m/s of forward velocity change with his "jump" -- the difference between velocity in low orbit and [Earth escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity).

Comment: Ok that helps a lot.  I'm trying to visualize it in my head as well.  In my project, the capsule is moving faster than the ISS, so I'm also assuming that the difference in speed at which the astronaut jumps out and is traveling at and let's say when he misses the ISS, is large enough that it would cause him to have a different inclination there for never coming in contact with the station again.  In my project he never makes it back I'm just trying to figure out if there would be a way for him to meet up with the ISS again, I'm hoping not. lol

Comment: If the capsule is closing with the ISS from behind, it's moving faster, and thus has a slightly higher apogee and slightly longer orbital period; if the astronaut jumps sideways, the astronaut's inclination will be different from the ISS inclination as well. The combination of those two features means it will be a long time before the astronaut meets the ISS again.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!!

Comment: If it matters, if not rescued before then, atmospheric drag will cause the astronaut's body to reenter the Earth's atmosphere and burn up in something like a year or two. (It varies significantly with not-completely predictable solar activity, so you can't predict the reentry time far in advance.)

Comment: I figured with about 7 or 8 hours of air he wouldn't stand a chance of survival but floating around the earth for a year or two would make that a bit more interesting and a bit morbid actually.

Comment: sorry for the edit, I just thought that some readers would benefit from seeing where the 3000 comes from.

Comment: That's pretty opaque IMO. Without adding a lot of definitions, it's meaningless to me. I'll summarize the significance of the 3000, er, 3500 m/s without a formal derivation instead.